# Fastest way of checking if a number is within a range

Tags: c#

What is the easiest way of checking if a number is within a range, besides

```
if (Enumerable.Range(1,100).Contains(number))
//true

if (x >= 1 && x <= 100)
//true
```

these ways? Something perhaps more effective?

Comment: Whats wrong with the second? It's efficient

Comment: What do you consider "easy"? By "fastest" do you mean speed of execution, or speed of typing in the code?

Comment: Always relevant when asking about "faster" code: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: If it's integers, the first will definitely be slower for many cases - e.g. if the range is large and the number isn't contained, every value will be compared to the number. Just do the second method - two integer comparisons is going to be faster than >2 integer comparisons.

Comment: Fastest at runtime

Comment: I'd go and talk to our boss if programmer sitting next to me uses first instead of second.

Comment: @hatchet did someone ever meant "typing in the code" when talking about "fast"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's nothing more efficient than the second option. You could write an extension:

```
public static class NumberExtensions
{
    public static bool IsWithinRange<T>(this T number, T rangeStart, T rangeEnd) where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        return number.CompareTo(rangeStart) >= 0 && number.CompareTo(rangeEnd) <= 0;
    }
}
```

Now the code is readable and efficient:

```
if (x.IsWithinRange(1, 100))
{

}
```

Comment: Instead of writing it for each number, could you not do this once on an IComparable<T> ?

Answer (score 2):

The first (LINQ) option is *horribly* inefficient. The second option (just check with inequality operators) is fine. In the general case when you have multiple ranges, you can use the new `switch` improvements:

```
    switch(number)
    {
        case var n when n >= 1 && n <= 100:
            // ...
            break;
        case var n when n > 100:
            // ...
            break;
        default:
            // ...
            break;
    }
```